# Web application doesn't respond after publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have developed a simple ASP.NET Core app using my Visual Studio 2015 and tested it on a local machine. Everything was running according to expectations.

After uploading it to my webhosting server (via FTP), it suddenly stops displaying the actual pages.

What I mean is that I can see that routing is working correctly (I was immediately navigated to `/Auth/Login` as I was not logged in the application (even though that the original address was `/App/Index`, but for unknown reason, I can only see a blank page (there is nothing when I inspect the page).

Just to mention - Due to the way how my web server works & how the folder structure is managed, I had to rename all instances of **wwwroot** to **www_root**; but I already did that...and it was working normally with my previous application.

What could be wrong here? Why my views were not injected properly to the app?

**EDIT 1 - More Info**

Here is how I do my authentification:

Setup under *Startup.cs*

```
        services.AddIdentity<IP_User, IdentityRole>(config =>
        {
            config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            config.Password.RequiredLength = 5;
            config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login";
            config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
            {
                OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
                {
                    if ((ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"))
                    && ctx.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            };

        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ShoppingContext>();
```

and under AuthController:

```
public class AuthController : Controller
    {
        private SignInManager<IP_User> _signInManager;

        public AuthController(SignInManager<IP_User> signInManager)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        // GET: /<controller>/
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "App");
            }

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel vm, string ReturnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(vm.Username, vm.Password, true, false);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "App");
                else
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or Password incorrect.");
            }

            return View();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Auth");
        }
    }
```

Where `IP_User` is just an inherited `IdentityUser`

Comment: Have you tried hosting it on your local IIS instance (i.e NOT through Express with VS)?

Comment: not really, I haven't found a way how to set it up as I could not get it to work last time

Comment: I think it'll be easier to troubleshoot if you figure out how to deploy locally first before using a remote webhost. The last time you tried to set it up locally - did it behave exactly the same?

Comment: Last time I deployed it to the web server I did not have any problems with it

Comment: I'm confused. "I could not get it to work last time" - but now you're saying the last time worked fine? Are we still talking about your local IIS instance?

Comment: Does any part of the app work on the deployed site? Can you hit static resources for example? What are you using for authentication?

Comment: I may have misunderstood regarding IIS, I have tried to set up my IIS previously but I did not manage to, therefore I have never deployed locally to IIS. Regarding the static resources - there is absolutely nothing in the background - no static files, no nothing :( I have added more core to show how I do authentification

Comment: To rule out a problem with the authentication pages themselves, can you create a new View which doesn't require authentication first, so that we can see if it gets served up?

Comment: Also I think what @LDJ is referring to is - can you view something like the CSS file if you browse to the file directly through the site? In other words: http://localhost:1234/Content/Site.css

Comment: Thank you for your tips! What I ended up doing (by reading the other posts) was to completely remove my old Publish profile and re-create it. This helped (there was probably some internal build problem)

Comment: Ah, good. I've noticed that sometimes I get strange behavior if I don't 'Delete all files prior to publish' as well, because some dll's in the /bin/ folder are stale. I'd suggest answering your own question with the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

In the end I have managed to solve the problem by deleting old Publish folder, removing Publish profile and completely re-publishing my entire website.

Comment: That sounds like you might have been migrating from RC1 to RTM (read: from DNX to dotnet-cli)?